# Convert Spring Integration Graph to image

Tags: spring-integration, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot Actuator provides us with an `integrationgraph` endpoint, which exposes a graph containing all Spring Integration components.

Graph can be consumed as `json`:

```sh
curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/integrationgraph \
  --request GET \
  --header 'accept: application/json'
```

But is there any known tool which can create an image / dot-graph / plantUML from this `json`, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tool but for sure there is one out there.

For JavaScript/HTML there is a gist:

https://ordina-jworks.github.io/architecture/2018/01/27/Visualizing-your-Spring-Integration-components-and-flows.html

Comment: And the Spring Flo sample app mentioned in the blog is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-flo/tree/angular-1.x/samples/spring-flo-si) and you can see an example of that in [this sample's README](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp).

Answer (score 0):

You can  use also Spring  Diagram in IntelliJ Idea
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-diagrams.html